# How to list usb devices ? Enables UWP API for Node.js (Chakra )

Tags: node.js, windows, windowsiot, chakra

1.my code

```
   var uwp=require("uwp");

   uwp.projectNamespace("Windows");
   var deviceInformation = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;   
   var VID=0x10C4;
   var PID=0x81B9;
    deviceInformation.findAllAsync().done(
      function(devices){
        console.log(devices);
      },
       function(err){
         console.log(err);
      } 
   );
```

2.result:
    Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection {

```
'0': Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation {},

'1': Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation {},

'2': Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation {},

'3': Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation {},

..........

'785': Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation {} }
```

3.Reference:
[Windows API reference for Windows Runtime apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/zn-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)

I alerady use :

Windows.Devices.Enumeration

Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Pnp

Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice

Windows.Devices.Usb

but still return empty object 。

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
nodejs: Node.js (Chakra) node@6.0.0

The device can display at Device Manager

info:

USB\VID_10C4&PID_81B9\5&369d87d2&0&1。

Guid: {745A17A0-74D3-11D0-B6FE-00A0C90F57DA}

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the devices, try the following code to get the device id.

```
var uwp = require("uwp");
uwp.projectNamespace("Windows");
var deviceInformation = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;
deviceInformation.findAllAsync().done(
function (devices) {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        console.log(devices[i].id);
    }
},
function (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
);
```